# Can other computers in the same lan access my Mac?

Tags: mac, security

I use a simple password on my Mac for my daily logins. I would like to know if it is vulnerable to remote access.

Can other computers on the same lan access my Mac if they know the username, password and IP address?

Comment: Simple answer is yes - however if you want to do this properly then use ssh and not use the password and use bonjour or some local DNS so access it by name. To get a useful answer please supply more details of the scenario you are in. Also if the routers are setup correctly you don't even need to be on the same lan

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @nohillside My password is simple for daily login, but if other computers can log in my Mac use it, I have to use a long complex password.

Comment: Anybody can walk up to your Mac and try to login, so a non-simple password is advisable anyway. But please edit your question to focus on the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: **YES**

Longer answer: Remote access is possible if you have enabled it in the Sharing pane in System Preferences.

But: A weak password also makes it easier to login while you are away, and/or to guess it from observing your fingers while you type. So if you value your privacy and your data, do yourself a favor and set a strong one.